# What's the error with my code?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, smarty

I'm using smarty template and php. The following code is being written in smarty template.

```
{literal}
<script type="text/javascript">
// This function gets test when category checkbox is checked

function get_subjects_by_class(class_id) {
    var field_id = 'subjects';
    $.ajax({
        url: "teacher_details.php",
        type: "GET",
        data: {
            'request_type': 'ajax',
            'op': 'get_assigned_subject_list',
            'class_id': class_id
        },  
        success: function (data) {
            $('#category_test_container').append(data);
        });
    }
</script>
{/literal}
```

Call to this function is as follows :

```
<a href="#" onClick="get_subjects_by_class({$class.class_id}); return false;">{$class.class_name}</a>
```

Upon clicking on hyperlink I'm getting an error as follows :

```
ReferenceError: $ is not defined
$.ajax({
```

I googled it for the error resolution, but couldn't get the desired resolution. Can anyone help me out to resolve this error? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Are you sure you loaded jquery plugin?

Comment: that means jquery.js file is missing... make sure you loaded the jquery script

Comment: First load jQuery and then load this script.

Comment: What browser are you using to test?  Try hitting F12 and checking the `scripts` tab to make sure jquery is loading correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either haven't loaded jQuery or you've loaded it after you've run this script.  This is why `$` is undefined.

Comment: As per your suggestion I added jquery library, now it's not giving that error but giving another error " 

$(document).ready(function(){"
Now how to get rid off this error?

Comment: @phpLover, is that the complete error message or is there more?

Comment: Is your code inside a `ready` function? As in: `$(function(){ // your code here }` or `$(document).ready(function(){ // your code here }`.

Comment: @phpLover, if your new error is still `ReferenceError: $ is not defined` but now followed by `$(document).ready(function(){`, this means that somewhere on your page you have a document ready script and you've run it before you've loaded jQuery.  It's essentially the same error.  You have to load jQuery before you can use any jQuery methods, not just stick it at the end of the list of scripts.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include jQuery first before the $ variable becomes available. $ is the short for jQuery, so obviously jQuery isnt included at the point where $.ajax is run.

Comment: `$` is also used by other libraries, so it's not just "short for jQuery."  But in this case, obviously, `$.ajax()` is a jQuery method.

Comment: thanks for pointing it out. It obviously is jQuery here so I left it away :)

Answer (score 0):

it seems that jquery is not included on the page. Please include jquery from any CDN

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```

It can happen due to conflicts also for that case use

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/